# How to observe database delete events with Architecture Components

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have a DAO as follows.

```
@Dao
public interface PostDAO {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM posts order by time DESC")
    LiveData<List<Post>> getPosts();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    @NonNull
    void insert(Post... posts);

    @Delete
    void delete(Post post);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id")
    Post getPost(String id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id")
    LiveData<Post> getPostLiveData(String id);
}
```

I understand that I can listen for new added data with something like the following.

```
postDAO().getPosts().observe(builder.getLifecycleOwner(), data::postValue)
```

But how can I know when a post has been deleted?

Answer (score 2):

`LiveData<List<Post>> getPosts();` returns a `LiveData` that is updated by any `insert`, `update`, or `delete` done to the *Post* table.

So if you are observing the list initially, then you are already observing for inserts/updates/deletes.

Comment: But how can you tell specifically which event it is for? Checkout my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57948812/1219213

Answer (score 1):

You observe for all the items (`LiveData<List<Post>>`) and get notified with the new data as soon as something changes.

You may want to use the new [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) which can show you the affected changes.

Another way is to set/update the value of your LiveData after deleting. Returning Long means that it returns the count of the deleted rows.

```
@Delete void delete(Post post) : Long

LiveData data = new MutableLiveData<Post>()
if (yourDao.delete(yourItem) > 0) data.setValue( yourItem )
```

I wrote an answer why Delete and Insert is not using LiveData at [Android Room : LiveData callback of update insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462128/android-room-livedata-callback-of-update-insert)

Comment: your answer before the edit about using Single can you elaborate on that in the comment.

Comment: Dont know what you mean :-) You can either check for changes using some kind of DiffUtil (or the android provided helper for that) or you use the attempt ive posted using another MutableLiveData<> which get notified as soon as data has been changed. Depends on the use case. If you have a "big" list the approach using a new LiveData Object is the best way to go.

Comment: Shouldn't it be wise to encourage using the "DiffUtil routine" over setValue()? I've been using data.setValue();, with post though, something's just not right with it.

Comment: i understand. i thought i saw something related to Single before the edit. Anyway i got your point.