# How to get the id of inserted row in android room databse in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I am trying to get the user ID from the newest user. How can I make the insert method spit the ID when the ID is autogenerated?

in Model

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val userId: Int
```

in Dao

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   fun addUserWithLong(user: User): LiveData<Long>
```

in Repository

```
fun addUserWitLong(user: User): LiveData<Long> {
        return userDao.addUserWithLong(user)
    }
```

in ViewModel

```
fun addUserWithLong(user: User): LiveData<Long> {
        return repository.addUserWitLong(user)
    }
```

in Fragment

```
val id: Long? = userViewModel.addUserWithLong(user).value
```

I have read in the docs that @Insert returns Long as the row ID but I do not know how to program it. Now the error is "Not sure how handle insert method return type." Is there some way to make with LiveData and not with Rxjava. That is without the need to download more dependecies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert)

> If the @Insert method receives a single parameter, it can return a
> long value, which is the new rowId for the inserted item. If the
> parameter is an array or a collection, then the method should return
> an array or a collection of long values instead, with each value as
> the rowId for one of the inserted items. To learn more about returning
> rowId values, see the reference documentation for the @Insert
> annotation, as well as the SQLite documentation for rowid tables

So you can use it like

```
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   long addUserWithLong(user: User)
```

or if you are inserting a list

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long[] addUserWithLong(user: List<User>)
```

**Edit-1**

After checking answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462128/android-room-livedata-callback-of-update-insert) post.

> No, you can't. I wrote an answer to the issue. The reason is, that
> LiveData is used to notify for changes. Insert, Update, Delete won't
> trigger a change.

I just created a test project and successfully received Id of last inserted item in activity. Here is my implementation.

**Dao**

```
@Insert
suspend fun addUser(user: Users): Long
```

**Repo**

```
suspend fun insertUser(context: Context, users: Users): Long {
        val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(context)
        val dao = db.userDao()
        return dao.addUser(users)
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
 fun addUser(context: Context, users: Users) = liveData {
//you can also emit your customized object here. 
        emit("Inserting...")
        try {
            val userRepo = UsersRepo()
            val response = userRepo.insertUser(context, users)
            emit(response)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            emit(e.message)
        }
    }
```

**Activity**

```
viewModel.addUser(applicationContext, user).observe(this, Observer { userId ->
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Inserted User Id is $userId")
        })
```

Check test application [here](https://github.com/khushwaqt/TestApplication).

Comment: I understand that but I am supposed to call the function from not the main thread. And do not know how to achieve that with out LiveData.

Comment: If you want it with livedata than in fragment/activity you should do this. Rest of your code if fine. 
viewModel.addUserWitLong(user).observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{id->
            Tiimber.d( "Inserted ID is $id")
        })

Comment: I keep getting this error in Dao. error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.

Comment: And I do not want it specifically with LiveData I just need to get it not from main thread. I thought using LiveData or make the function suspend. But I do not know how to make it work either way.

Comment: It works well enough. But it takes a little while to get the ID. And since I am using fragment in observe I replaced this with viewLifeCycleOwner. It worked with requireActivity as well.
The ID should not be used inside the Observer{} because it takes a while to aquire it.